# ValueError: time data '00:01:29:06' does not match format '%d:%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert dataframe in columns duration to datetime format to anlysis average or max/min but it now work need some help thanks.
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52aXG.png)

```
df['duration'] =pd.to_datetime(df['duration'], format='%d:%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken `%d` (day) shall be between `01` and `31`. `00` would not match the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is that the `%d` format only accepts values between `01` and `31` (since it stands for "day of the month"). `00` is then not valid.

The best workaround I could figure (someone might suggest something better) is to use regular expression to convert the strings contained in the `duration` column into some valid string as in the following example:

```py
df['duration']=pd.to_timedelta(df.duration.str.replace(r"(?P<day>\d+):", r'\g<day> days ', 1))
```

I've no idea about the time complexity of the above example (in case of have a big table to convert).

Comment: Thank sir, and how to fix it. i use "df['duration'] =pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])" but error show "ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format".

Comment: Just edited the answer with a suggestion of workaround